# Exception:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting a HttpMessageNotReadableException when I try to do Post Message with Invalid value for Boolean field in java Spring boot with following Input:

```
{
 "User":"xyz",
 "email":"xyz@email.com",
 "isAdmin":"No"    ( This is Boolean in my API Bean expecting true or false) 
}
```

I am getting below error messages in Console and response body respectively:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'yes': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 29, column: 29]
```

Below Response body:

```
{
"Code": "JSON_REQUEST_INVALID",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'yes': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized token 'yes': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 29, column: 7] (through reference chain: com.sample.model.apibeans.userDetails[\"user\"])",
"path": "/userapi/v1"
```

}

However i want error Message to be more specific like 'yes' is Not Allowed in Field "isAdmin"! as the above message doesn't give much information about which field has caused error.

I have used below @ControllerAdvice to catch and override the message, however i am not able to get the field in which this error occurred. Below is the Exception handling method implementation.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
protected Errors handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(InputMismatchException ex, WebRequest request) {

    Errors errors = new Errors();
    Error error;
    error = new Error();
    error.setParams(null);
    error.setMessage("Json Contains "+ex.getCause());
    error.setTraceId(request.getHeader(TRACE_ID_HEADER_NAME));
    error.setStatus(Integer.toString(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()));
    error.setCode("JSON_REQUEST_INVALID");
    errors.addErrorsItem(error);
    return errors;
}
```

Ex object doesn't provides any method to get the Path or Field where this occurred. How can i get that information to provide more specific error message to consumer.

Note: I am using Spring Boot 2.2.1

I already saw other Similar Questions on Stack-overflow however non of them was able to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do respond with redundant information which is already present with the reponse line?

Comment: @Michael-O well not really redundant information, the current message is redundant "Unrecognized token 'yes': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')" , This expecting part has nothing to do with Boolean Data type, i get this even if DataType is Number and Consumer sends a String. So this Error i stated is Redundant.

Comment: Status code and reason phrase are redundant.

Comment: @Michael-O i agree but that's not the real issue,that's just a sample message , it's not actual response. so please ignore redundancy and let's focus on main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i didn't yet get the java method to get the exact field however due to a pattern in error i concluded the below field extraction that can be useful.

```
 String  param= (String) ex.getMessage().subSequence(ex.getMessage().lastIndexOf("[")+1,ex.getMessage().lastIndexOf("]"));
```

This fetch the exact field where the error occurred and you provide a dynamic message to the client like below:

```
  {
"Code": "JSON_REQUEST_INVALID",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "unexpected value at isAdmin",
"path": "/userapi/v1"
}
```